# Copy android contacts' birthday to calendar

Tags: android, facebook, calendar, contacts

I'm an htc tattoo owner, and i'm watching for a way to copy contacts' birthday (retrieved from facebook) to the built-in calendar.

I'm not afraid to develop a custom app but i'll be more happy if there's one built-in or already existing...

Thinking over this thing, i realized there's more fun creating a custom app... :P

Do you know if there's a way to read contacts' informations and write it to the calendar?

Comment: I'm not sure this is really programming related. I'm sure you'd have better luck asking around the various Android forums. Perhaps if you rephrased your question to address the technicals of implementing this inside a custom app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the following link to read contacts data :

http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Working-With-Android-Contacts/1/

For Calendar:
You need to build the CalendarProvider from sources and install it. It has the APIs which will allow you to save the events into the calendar.

Comment: Thanks, i think (seen the complexity of the older code) I'll wait the release of android 2.1 for my phone(now it has 1.6 version) to develop this application... I hope this happen soon... :D